# Multithreading for reading csv files python

Tags: python, multithreading, csv

How do i parse a large (about 5GB) in python?

My current datafile parser takes LOTS of time

```
def parse_data(file, op_file_test):
        with open(file, 'rb') as inf:
                incsv = csv.reader(x.replace('\0', '') for x in inf)
                col1, col2 = defaultdict(Counter), defaultdict(Counter)
                for c1,c2,label in incsv:
                        try:
                                col1[label][c1] += 1
                                col2[label][c2] += 1
                        except ValueError:
                                pass

        map_file =  open(op_file_test,'a')
        labels = sorted(col1)
        for lbl in labels:
                print >>map_file, "%s, %s, %s, %s, %s" % (lbl, col1[lbl][str(0)], col1[lbl][str(1)], col2[lbl][str(0)],col2[lbl][str(1)])
        map_file.close()
```

What would be the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: How much time is it taking currently ? How much time does it take to simply read the entire file line by line ? If there is some difference between steps 1 and 2, the your parsing logic should be the one thats taking more time.

Comment: I would recommend to profile your current script before diving into multithreading. Also, in python you wont scale with multithreading, you have to multi process it with memory mapping the file and assigining chunks of that file to each process and then later merging the results

Comment: It takes more than 30minutes and that's a LONG time. I should be able to use all the processors and make it faster!

Comment: @ArunMu:Can you shoot an example?

Comment: @pistal: if you want to utilise all the cores available to you in Python, you'll have to use the multiprocessing package to sidestep the GIL.

Comment: Can you give the timings on the two read methods ? Multithreading wont scale in Python coz of GIL, instead you can use multiprocessing. For Eg: Read 1 MB chunk and assign that to 1 worker process, nect 1 MB to another process like that..Chunk size is what will control the performance in this design.

Comment: Also, what is your computer architecture, 32 bit or 64 bit ? RAM size ? number of Cores ?

Comment: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz

Comment: I recommend you to read this link: http://effbot.org/zone/wide-finder.htm

Comment: The following two lines mean you'r looping over it twice. They could be combined into one loop as a start...

*** incsv = csv.reader(x.replace('\0', '') for x in inf) ***

for c1,c2,label in incsv:

Comment: and how do we combine them?